# Queue, stack python

Tags: python, stack, queue

"You will write the Python class Queue. It will have two slots: stack1 and stack2. You will also write the maker function mkQueue that takes no arguments and initializes both slots to the empty stack." So, i have this:, but I am not sure whether it is asking me to leave the parameters empty or put stack in it?

```
class Queue():
    __slots__ = ('stack1', 'stack2')

def mkQueue(stack1, stack2):
    Queue.stack1 = stack1
    Queue.stack2 = stack2
    return Queue
```

Comment: ignore the single quote marks in mkQueue() function

Comment: I don't know if I answered your question or not, but it was interesting to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a step in the right direction for you, with some comments that meet the terms of your assignment. It's unlikely that this is the full implementation that you need, but it should get you started.

```
class Queue():
    __slots__ = ('stack1', 'stack2')

    def __init__(self): # You need to define an initialize method
        self.stack1 = []
        self.stack2 = []    

    # staticmethods are the only kinds of class methods that take no arguments
    @staticmethod  
    def mkQueue(): 
        return Queue()
```

usage:

```
>>> foo = Queue.mkQueue()
>>> foo.stack1
[]
>>> foo.stack2
[]
>>> foo.stack1 is foo.stack2
False
```

Comment: i thought you cannot put another function under a class?

Comment: Classes typically have more than one function. If they only have one function, you're typically better off putting the function directly in the module. Classes become important when you need functionality dependent on data contained in multiple instances.

Comment: well now i know, since our professor hasn't told us yet